# How to use pymongo to process huge collections

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

I was looking all over the web for my problem but kind of got stuck, I'm trying to use pymongo to go over a huge collection on MongoDB using cursors, however it seams that there is no hasNext() implementation in python like JS.

Here is my code:

```
cursor = news.find() 
while(cursor.hasNext()):    
     doc = cursor.next()
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

pymongo has no hasNext(), instead the method next() returns None if there is no more objects , so this is the trick

Thanks eitherway!

Answer (score 1):

you can go over the collection by **for** statement

```
for record in cursor:
  print record
```

The **for** keyword actually calls **_*iter*_()** and **next()** for you.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Iterator

**Cursor** object in pymongo come with these 2 methods.
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py#L1010